# Web API model validation

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing a new Web API and I have a user model which is being used for CRUD operations.However due to the nature of our business whenever a client posts data to create a new user, they are supposed to first send us their userid and then internally we create our own userid and this userid is sent back and the client is supposed to now use this newly generated id that we gave them for any future reference to our system.

The problem :
I have a single User model which has property :

ExternalClientId : This is the ID that the external client calling the API will send
UserId : This is the newly generated ID from our system that will be sent back to the client.

Now in my validation I need to make sure the user always passes the ExternalClientId in the POST since that is my key to generate a new ID, thus I have the data annotation:

```
[Required]
ExternalClientId
```

However, when it comes to Update (PUT) the user is supposed to pass the generated "UserId" and at this point the ExternalClientId is no longer a required attribute, how do I manage this in a single user model ?

I was also thinking of having seperate user models for each method, however I am not sure if that is the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could move the required field logic into the method itself and return an exception if the model doesn't validate, or rather add an attribute to the API method instead of the model. That way either the POST or PUT method could accept the same input class, but only one of them would require a valid field of `ExternalClientID`

To make it even more generic, you could have a custom attribute like this:

```
[RequiredField("ExternalClientID")]
public ClientModel Post(ClientModel c) ...

public ClientModel Put(ClientModel c) ...
```

Alternatively, you could use different models, which in my opinion is a totally valid approach.

Comment: Interesting, I know I can just not use annotations at all and just write custom validation in my method to check if some property is required in the CREATE vs UPDATE, however I would like to explore the custom attribute generic approach that you mentioned.

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi full disclosure: I haven't written many custom attributes so it might take some investigation and experimenting, but to keep with the attribute approach I'm sure you could work something out. Keeping it generic like that is a good way to go. You'd also have to do some thinking about situations where your method has more than one input parameter.